# using constexpr to return pointer

Tags: c++, c++20, constexpr

Since C++20 we can allocate memory during compile time and we have to free that during compile time. Therefore this raised some questions for me:
first why does this work?

```
constexpr int* return_ptr() {
    return new int{ 1 };
}

void call_return_ptr(){
    int* int_ptr = return_ptr();
}

int main() {
    call_return_ptr();
    return 0;
}
```

I'm using the ptr returned from `constexpr` and *not* freeing that during compile time. This should be an error based on what I've understood.
Secondly if the first example works then why this shouldn't work:

```
constexpr int* return_ptr() {
    return new int{ 1 };
}

void call_return_ptr(){
    constexpr int* int_ptr = return_ptr();
}

int main() {
    call_return_ptr();
    return 0;
}
```

and even if we try to delete the pointer during compile time like this:

```
constexpr int* return_ptr() {
    return new int{ 1 };
}

constexpr void call_return_ptr(){
    constexpr int* int_ptr = return_ptr();
    delete int_ptr;
}

int main() {
    call_return_ptr();
    return 0;
}
```

this is still an error. What is going on here?

---EDIT
Nicol Bolas gave a very good and profound answer to first and somewhat second part of my question, but that still leaves why the third version (the one that `call_return_ptr` is also constexpr) isn't working. Based what's on the comments on Nicol Bolas's answer, it is still unclear to me, why even if we change the third version's function signature to `consteval` that still gives an error since everything in `call_return_ptr` should be in a `constexpr` context.

Comment: `constexpr` functions can be called both a compile-time and run-time, so the fact that the first example works doesn't imply that the second should.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There is no such thing as "compile-time". Not really.

What there is is "constant expression evaluation". These are a certain category of expressions whose evaluation happens in a certain way, such that the results of their evaluation are available to the source code.

A `constexpr` function is a function which *may be* evaluated during constant expression evaluation. If you call it outside of a constant expression context, then it does not undergo constant expression evaluation.

The initializer for a `constexpr` (or `constinit`) variable is a constant expression context. Therefore, it must undergo constant expression evaluation.

The rules for constant expression memory allocation only apply when the function is called within a constant expression context. So your first `call_return_ptr` calls `return_ptr` and stores the result in a runtime variable. This is not a constant expression context; it's just regular expression evaluation. The function allocates memory and returns a pointer, just like any other.

Your second version uses the result of that call to `return_ptr` to initialize a `constexpr` variable. This *is* a constant expression context... right up until the variable finishes initialization. See, you called `call_return_ptr` outside of a constant expression context, so the only part of that function which is a constant expression context is the initialization of the `constexpr` variable. Everything else, including the `delete` call, is not part of a constant expression context.

So unless you call this function within a constant expression context, you'll get a compile error since constant evaluation produced a pointer to constexpr allocated memory that was not deleted in that constant evaluation.

If you want to ensure that a particular function is *always* a constant expression context, it must be declared `consteval`.

The third one doesn't work for more or less the same reason: the function is not being called in a constant expression context. Indeed, a `void` function cannot itself be in a constant expression context unless it is `consteval`, since there is no result of a `void` function to use in constant evaluation.

Furthermore, by making the inner variable `constexpr`, you have created a constant expression context *within* the function. The thing is, the rules of constant evaluation are recursive. A constant expression context must not leak memory, *even if* that context is evaluated *within* another constant expression context. Each constant expression context has to follow those rules, regardless of the context outside of its evaluation.

Comment: Thank you for your time and your profound answer. I've read your answer and I couldn't figure out why the third version is an error. Because based on what you have said it is being called in a constexpr context and I'm freeing the memory, so why is there an error? I fully understood the problem with first and second versions though.

Comment: @ClassY: "*Because based on what you have said it is being called in a constexpr context*" No, it isn't. The expression calling the function does not use the return value to initialize a `constexpr` variable. Also, it's a `void` function, so the return value *cannot* initialize a `constexpr` variable. So the function call itself is not a constant expression context; only the initialization of the `constexpr` variable inside of the function is a constant expression context.

Comment: But why the compiler decides that the third version doesn't need to be a constexpr and removed it? And I also tried the third version again by changing the function signature from constexpr to consteval and it still failed!

Comment: @ClassY: Did you leave the variable `constexpr`? If so... why?

Comment: because I'm not going to change where the pointer is pointing to and since its already in a constexpr context the only meaning it has is applying const. The reasoning is besides the point I'm making, could you please help me on why that gives an error(third version with changes that we talked about in the comments)?

Comment: @ClassY: "*The reasoning is besides the point*" No, it is the point because that `constexpr` is why it still doesn't work. A `constexpr` initializer is a constant expression context. And a pointer isn't allowed to leak from a constant expression context even into *another* constant expression context.

Comment: The fact is that we can pass it to another `constexpr` function, see my code example at [this codeshare link](https://codeshare.io/K8joRK). It can be compiled with gcc -std=c++20.  Since everything is in `constexpr` context it should work and it does! then why adding `constexpr` to pointer itself isn't allowed? The pointer is known at compile time since it created at compile time then 1- why is that an error 2-why do we even have to make it `consteval` , why does the compiler decides to remove the `constexpr` from the function in third version.

Comment: @ClassY: I don't know what more I can tell you. A constant expression context is a constant expression context and follows the rules therein *even within another such context*. By declaring the variable to be `constexpr`, you have created a *new* context within the existing context. And the inner context must follow the rules of a constant expression context *within itself*.

Comment: Oh my! I thought if its within a `constexpr` context then adding any more `constexpr` wouldn't create a new `constexpr` context because it seems redundant to me[if its compile time for the caller, then every call within it, is  still compile time all the way down]. thanks for your time! I really appreciate that, I finally understand.